# Control a SWF Flash Loop

Tags: flash, loops

We are going to make a lot of small flash animations with different messages, and put them on a big screen. They will be saved as SWF files.

Is there a framework or anything that enable us to make a easy controller for this, so we can control both a loop, but also play a specific clip when we want?

If you got any Questions or need more infomation, just ask!

Thanks for the help!

I need:
1. To load all SWF's from a folder.
2. Loop SWF's
3. Play some SWF's on demand, and then continue loop

Comment: There are many, many ways to do that - you could control it via javascript, or have some script to load the files, or you could have a parent SWF to control the children SWF, etc. There's no framework to do that. You'll need a custom solution.

Comment: I have not heard of such a framework too. So let's think of custom solution. Can you please describe better what exactly you want (e.g. enumerate required functions)? What does "controll" stand for?

Comment: I want it to be smooth, I think a javascript would make it blink. I have now found http://www.onyx-vj.com seems like I can use it, but it is a bit overkill.

Comment: The smoothest way would be to not use multiple SWFs. Simply have one main .fla and use packages to organize the various animations. Then you can simply hide/show the animations you need, without any loading time.

Comment: @Laurent I want to add SWF's on the fly, and I need too control what clip is next ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a control SWF that included other SWF files from a xml file.

It then detected how many frames the clip was. When it was on the last frame it unloaded the clip and replaced it with the next on the list.